# change directory to USB disk

Tags: external-hdd, cd-command

I can not change to a directory that is placed in an USB disk. But I am able to change to the internal disks directories by using the cd command.

When I type `df-h` to identify the external disk name, it returns [this summary of available and used disk space usage of file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7W2g.jpg). `sdb1` is the external disk.

If I type `cd /media/angel/ADATA HD710` (I copied `/media/angel/ADATA HD710` from the `df -h` command result, to make sure I don't have a typo), then I get `bash: cd: /media/angel/ADATA:No such file or directory`

However if I type `cd /media/angel/43DC-66BE` (which corresponds to a partition of an internal disk) I get `angel@millonario:/media/angel/43DC-66BE$`.

How can I change to `/media/angel/ADATA HD710`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
cd /media/angel/ADATA\ HD710/
```

Comment: You are awsome!! Thank you so much, I worked. I really appreciate it!

Comment: backslash is needed in names with spaces. Also, you can type: cd /media/angel/ADATA and when press TAB button. Bash will help you to complete the query

Comment: Thank you again for the explanation, and your kindness!  you rock!

Comment: Another way is to place path in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Also, use quotes for string with spaces:

```
cd "/media/angel/ADATA HD710/"
cd '/media/angel/ADATA HD710/'
```